# EAGLE - StopMask DRC Error

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad, drc

I cant understand what this DRC error means.

[image]

Especially I do not understand this box. Does it mean that the Soldermask will cover part of the pad? How to correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to the fact that your reference designator font is "proportional", not "vector".

Proportional fonts in eagle are collision detected with a rectangular box which is what the DRC is erroring about - the bounding box of the ref-des intersects the stop mask.

Vector font converts to a series of lines so collision detects the actual lines rather than the bounding box.

I'd recommend always using vector font. In fact there is a setting in the layout editor options for converting all fonts to vector.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you. I would never guess myself.

Comment: @P__J__ confused me for a while when I first started using Eagle too.